# Resize Image to match Target Image in design system

Tags: html, css, image, web, accessibility

[image]

This is the HTML, the image is contained in the hero-section within the hero container, the image I am working on is the one with class = "tablet". i am trying to replicate the image where the image is offset towARDS THE right side of the screen. I HAVE FOUND IT HARD TO DECIDE ON HOW TO APPROACH THIS, I HAVE TRIED SCALE BUT THEN IT RESIZES VERY SMALL AS THE SCREEN WIDTH REDUCES. PLEASE TAKE A LOOK AT THE CODE AND ANY IDEAS WOULD BE APPRECIATED

[image]

```
    <title>Frontend Mentor | Skilled e-learning landing page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="nav">
      <span class="nav-item">skilled</span>
      <a href="#" class="btn nav-btn">Get Started</a>
    </nav>

    <section class="hero">
      <div class="hero-container">
        <h1 class="hero-header">Maximize skill, minimize budget</h1>

        <p class="hero-txt">
          Our modern courses across a range of in-demand skills will give you
          the knowledge you need to live the life you want.
        </p>

        <button class="btn hero-btn">Get Started</button>
      </div>
      <div class="img-container">
        <img alt=" " src="assets/HeroImageMobile.webp" class="mobile" />
        <img src="assets\image-hero-tablet@2x.png" alt="" class="tablet" />
      </div>
    </section>
    <main>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="courses">
          <h2 class="courses-header">Check out our most popular courses!</h2>
          <div class="course-desc">
            <img src="assets\icon-animation.svg" alt="" class="icons" />
            <h2 class="course-header">Animation</h2>
            <p>
              Learn the latest animation techniques to create stunning motion
              design and captivate your audience
            </p>
            <button class="btn main-btn">Get Started</button>
          </div>
          <div class="course-desc">
            <h2 class="course-header">Design</h2>
            <img src="assets\icon-Design.svg" alt="" class="icons" />

            <p>
              Create beautiful, usable interfaces to help shape the future of
              how the web looks.
            </p>
            <button class="btn main-btn">Get Started</button>
          </div>
          <div class="course-desc">
            <img src="assets\icon-photography.svg" alt="" class="icons" />
            <h2 class="course-header" 1>Photography</h2>
            <p>
              Explore critical fundamentals like lighting, composition, and
              focus to capture exceptional photos.
            </p>
            <button class="btn main-btn">Get Started</button>
          </div>
          <div class="course-desc">
            <img src="assets\icon-crypto.svg" alt="" class="icons" />
            <h2 class="course-header">Crypto</h2>
            <p>
              All you need to know to get started investing in crypto. Go from
              beginner to advanced with this 54 hour course.
            </p>
            <button class="btn main-btn">Get Started</button>
          </div>
          <div class="course-desc">
            <img src="assets\icon-business.svg" alt="" class="icons" />
            <h2 class="course-header">Business</h2>
            <p>
              A step-by-step playbook to help you start, scale, and sustain your
              business without outside investment.
            </p>
            <button class="btn main-btn">Get Started</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>

    <footer class="footer">
      <span>skilled</span>
      <a href="" class="btn footer-btn"> Get Started</a>
    </footer>
  </body>


//CSS

:root{
    --Scampi:hsl(234, 25%, 52%);
    --Bunting:hsl(233,54%,16%);
    --waterloo: hsl(232,10%,56%);
    --Violet-Red: hsl(341,92%,62%);
    --carnation-pink: hsl(341,100%,83%);
    --white:#ffffff;
    --roseGrad: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(240,42,166,1) 0%, rgba(255,111,72,1) 100%);
    --DodgerGrad: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(72,81,255,1) 0%, rgba(240,42,166,1) 100%);


}

html{
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(255,255,255,1) 40%, rgba(240,241,255,1) 100%);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
}
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
  }
body{

    line-height: 1.2;
     font-family: 'Plus Jakarta Sans', sans-serif;;
     width: 100%;
     margin: 0;
    
     
    
   
}
body > *{
    margin-bottom: 0.9rem;
    padding: 0rem 0.7rem;
    
}
img{
    max-width: 100%;
}


a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--white);
}
.btn{
    padding: 0.9rem 1.5rem;
    border-radius: 1.5rem;
    border: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Plus Jakarta Sans', sans-serif;;
    font-size: 1.2rem;


}

.nav-btn{
    background-color: var(--Bunting);
}


.hero-btn{
    background: var(--roseGrad);
    color: var(--white);
   
}

.main-btn{
    color: var(--Violet-Red);
    background-color: transparent;
}

.footer-btn{
    background: var(--DodgerGrad);
    color: white;
}
.nav{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-top: 1.5rem;
}
.nav-item{
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight:700 ;
    color: var(--Bunting);
}

.hero{
    padding: 1rem 0.7rem;
}

.hero-header{
    font-size: 2.3rem;
    
    color: var(--Bunting);
}

.hero-txt{

    color: var(--waterloo);
    font-size: 0.95rem;
    line-height: 1.7;
    text-align: left;

}


.img-container{

    margin-top: 1.5em;
}

.courses{
    line-height: 1.7;
}

.courses-header{
    color: white;
    background: var(--roseGrad);
    padding: 2rem;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
}
.main-btn{
    padding: 0;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.course-desc{
    background: var(--white);
    position: relative;
    margin: 2.8rem 0;
    padding: 1rem;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

.course-desc > p{
    color: var(--waterloo);
  

}


.icons{
    position: absolute;
    top: -10%;
}
.footer{
    background: var(--Bunting);
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 5rem;
    padding: 2.4rem 0.5rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 7rem;
}
.footer > span{
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.tablet{

    display: none;
}

.btn:hover{
    opacity: 0.4;
}
.courses, .hero, nav{
    width: min(95%, 80vw);
    margin: 0 auto;
}


@media(min-width:700px) {

    nav{
        padding: 1.4rem;
    }

    .hero{

        display: flex;
        gap: 1.5rem;
        padding:0 1.4rem;
        margin-top: 1.5rem;
        position: relative;
    }

    .hero-container{
        margin-top: 10.5rem;
        height: 50%;
    }

    .mobile{
        display: none;
    }

    .hero-container{
        flex-grow: 2;
    }

///This is the container for the image

    .img-container{

transform: scale(1.5);
position: relative;
left: 10rem;

        


 


/// THIS IS THE IMAGE DECLARATION

        
    }
    .tablet{
       display: inline-block;
       transform: scale(4rem);
       
       
       
       
        
    }
    main{
        margin-top: 3.5rem;
    }

    .courses{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
        gap: 1rem;
      
      
    }
    .courses, .hero, nav{
        width: 80%;
        max-width:950PX;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    
    .course-desc{
        padding:min(1.4rem,1.7rem)  ;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        /* width: 400px; */
        font-size: min(1rem, 2rem);

    }

    
    .courses-header{
        margin-Bottom:3rem;
    }

   
    .course-desc > p{
        height: 30%;
        margin: 0;
        margin-bottom: 2.5rem;
    }
    
    .main-btn{
        text-align: left;
    }

    .footer{
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    .footer > *{
        margin:  0 1rem;
    }



}

@media(min-width:1400px){

    .courses{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
        grid-template-rows: repeat(2,400px);
        gap: 1rem;
        padding:   1.5rem;
    }

  main, .hero, nav {
        width: 95%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }


    
    
.course-desc{
    padding:1.5rem 1rem
}

    .main-btn{
        margin-bottom: 2.5rem;
    }


    .hero, nav{
        width: 75%;
    }
    .courses{
        width: 2000px
    }
}
```

Comment: Are there any accessibility aspects you’d like to have considered as well, or did you add the tag by mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You can try having both the images in the same parent, give position relative to parent and then position absolute to the image which you want on the right side. And then write css for that image to have bottom and left properties to shift it towards right and top. Note that this common parent should not contain anything else except these two images.